# How to solve these inequations

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: show that  (  $x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right], a,b>0$)

$$a+b\leq \sqrt{a^2 \sin^2 x+b^2 \cos^2x}+\sqrt{a^2 \cos^2x+b^2 \sin^2x}\leq \sqrt{2} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: the word is "inequality"

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using $(x+y)^2 \le 2(x^2+ y^2)$ to show the right inequality.

For the left, squaring and canceling the same terms we get

$$ab\le \sqrt{(a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x)(a^2\cos^2x + b^2\sin^2x)},$$

the rest is yours.